# Cannot get alert() box in Selenium WebDriver with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, alert, selenium-chromedriver

### In brief

Today I cannot get my code here [00](https://github.com/namgivu/automation-testing/blob/master/util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box_00.py) [01](https://github.com/namgivu/automation-testing/blob/master/util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box_01.py) works to get javascript alert() box from Python with Selenium WebDriver.

### In full

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=selenium+python+javascript+alert&oq=selenium+python+alert+js&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.7583j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=selenium+python+javascript+alert+not+working+for+chrome+webdriver) on the topic gave me many results e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40261556/248616) using `EC.alert_is_present()` and `driver.switch_to_alert()`

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("...some page...")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

I follow that and write a simple code on my github here [00](https://github.com/namgivu/automation-testing/blob/master/util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box_00.py) [01](https://github.com/namgivu/automation-testing/blob/master/util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box_01.py) trying to access the alert object from Python code. Though I failed with the timeout exception as below i.e. the webdriver cannot get the alert() box object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box.py", line 49, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.alert_is_present()) #TODO Why alert box not available? We got error here
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

So if you know how to get it work, please share. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't worked in python and this is just a thought. Can you try executing the webdriver wait inside try/catch block? Also try using implicit wait after initiating the webdriver-->driver.implicitly_wait(10)#seconds

Comment: Thanks @santhoshkumar. May you clarify how a try/catch can help - I think it just turn off the exception but the fact remains that we cannot get the alert() box.

Comment: I have tried `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` and still get the timeout exception.

Comment: i agree with your question for try catch block. It's weird i know but sometime it worked for me. Again this is just a thought to try.

Comment: It is working fine on my machine. To check, alert is coming or not, add some using time.sleep(10) after clicking on try it button. I am able to see the alert dialog.

Comment: Wow really wait for 10 seconds @@ I will try though

Comment: @Murthi I tried time.sleep(10) and timeout still occurred.

Comment: @Murthi I also tested on simpler test and failed i.e. the alert() box show right when the page is loaded at https://github.com/namgivu/automation-testing/blob/master/util/sandbox/my_sandbox/test_alert_box_00.py

Comment: Is alert pops up? If not then problem with button click.

Comment: If we run the html file manually, all alert boxes are working fine. They just don't work when executed inside webdriver